# Handling Paramiko SSHException - Server connection dropped

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to copy files from remote server to my local directory.

I am using Python paramiko's sftp get to copy the files.

```
sftp.get(remote_pate, local_path)
```

After copying very few files, I get the following exception.

```
SSHException('Server connection dropped')
```

Establishing connection using,

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
```

Why does the connection get dropped? How can I handle this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any development on this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This would arise (as mentioned in the source, line no 667, http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.sftp_client-pysrc.html) when there is any error reading the packet or when there is EOFError

Comment: Thanks. In that case, can I skip over the files that causes EOFError? Any other way to get over this?